# Error in downloading

Tags: grub2

I want to create a DVD of my softwares installed on my Kubuntu. I tried to download APTONCD but it can't be downloaded. I tried it from Terminal and at 98% it gave error that files cannot get from server.
Is there any other software instead it? or is there any .Deb file(Aptoncd) to download easily?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu automatically saves all the installation packages (*.deb files) to:

> /var/cache/apt/archives

You don't need APTonCD. Just copy the entire **archives** folder to the place where you desire.

Before installing software, apt usually checks for packages inside the above cache directory. If packages are not found, or if they are out dated, apt will start downloading the packages off then Internet.